# missing datasources on visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2012, datasource

I cant seem to add a datasources in my visual studio 2012. I already download and install the MySQL for visual studio but it doesn't show the MySql Database on my datasources.  can you help guys?

[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD5Jt.png)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL .NET Connector follow this [HELP](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

[image]

Comment: Already done that but still no MySql Database in my datasource :(